# How to dismiss alertview when click on the button in that alertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS.

I am working on alertviews. Here is my code. Here there are 2 alertviews: `successfulallert` and `unsuccessfulallert` for login page. I am using alertview delegate also here, it will work for both alertviews but I want to work only for successful alertview and navigation should be done only for successful alertview. If anybody knows this please help me.

```
NSString *responseOfResult = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[result response]];
    NSRange match;
    //  NSLog(@"string= %@", str);
    match = [responseOfResult rangeOfString: @"successful"];
    if(match.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        UIAlertView *unsuccessfulAllert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                               message:responseOfResult
                               delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [unsuccessfulAllert show];

    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *successfulAllert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Login successful." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [successfulAllert show];
     }
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
        [[self navigationController]pushViewController:registerUserScreen animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you **put "OK" as cancelButtonTitle**? Everything will be handled automatically.

```
UIAlertView *successfulAllert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Login successful." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [successfulAllert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
        //POP here with this:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:addItemView animated:NO];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add tag to the two alert views and check for tag in alert view delegate.

Sample code:

```
NSString *responseOfResult = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[result response]];
NSRange match;
//  NSLog(@"string= %@", str);
match = [responseOfResult rangeOfString: @"successful"];
if(match.location == NSNotFound)
{
    UIAlertView *unsuccessfulAllert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                           message:responseOfResult
                           delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [unsuccessfulAllert setTag:1];
    [unsuccessfulAllert show];

}
else {
    UIAlertView *successfulAllert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Login successful." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [successfulAllert setTag:2];
    [successfulAllert show];
 }

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if(alertView.tag==2 && buttonIndex == 0){
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:registerUserScreen animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you're missing the `.tag` in the second `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the delegate would work for both the alertviews but you can assign a tag to each alertview Object and check for the tag in the delegate and then perform event if the tag for that particular AlertView onject matches.If u need code , i will provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *responseOfResult = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[result response]];
NSRange match;
//  NSLog(@"string= %@", str);
match = [responseOfResult rangeOfString: @"successful"];
if(match.location == NSNotFound)
{
    UIAlertView *unsuccessfulAllert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                           message:responseOfResult
                           delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [unsuccessfulAllert setTag:1];

    [unsuccessfulAllert show];

}
else {
    UIAlertView *successfulAllert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Login successful." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [successfulAllert setTag:2];
    [successfulAllert show];
 }
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if(alertView.tag == 2)
{
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:registerUserScreen animated:YES];
}
 else
 {
    //[[self navigationController]pushViewController:registerUserScreen animated:NO];
     // OR
     return;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to correct your code, the first and very common is to use the `tag` property (integer) of the `UIView`. Since `UIAlertview` inherits from `UIView`, it has the `tag` property, so each time you want create an alert (or a view), set the tag and the check your condition like:

```
...
alert.tag=1;
[alert show];
```

then to know wich alert is calling the callback:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
  if(alertView.tag==theTagOfYourAlert){
     //do your stuff
   }
}
```

another way, in your case, could be:

```
if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Alert"]){
       //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For things like Login status updates, you might want to have the "Login Successful" message disappear automatically. Try this instead:

https://github.com/camclendenin/flashbox

This works nicely and comes in handy for situations like this. Plus you don't have to deal with all the clutter involved with UIAlertViews.